# how to print same randomint after if/elif?

Tags: python-2.6

I want to get randint to be printed the same as in the if/elif statements each time it executes without a new integer returning. Also is there another way instead of having to write so much code after the while statement or is it fine?

```
from random import *
def randomchance():
    return randint(1, 100)
def randomknife():
    return randint(1, 8)
skins = ['blue', 'purple', 'pink', 'red']
knives = ['karambit', 'flip', 'bowie', 'butterfly', 'm9 bayonet', 'bayonet', 'daggers', 'falchion']
print 'Welcome to CS GO case lottery'
for skin in skins:
    print "Available", skin,
for knife in knives:
    print "Available", knife,
print '(blue = common, purple = uncommon, pink = rare, red = epic)'
keys = 10
while keys >0:
    resp=raw_input("Enter 'yes' to open a case: ")
    if (resp == str('yes') or resp == str('Yes')):
        print 'Opening case...'
        if (randomchance() >= 35):
            print 'You\'ve won a', skins[0]
        elif (randomchance() >= 20):
            print 'You\'ve won a', skins[1]
        elif (randomchance() >= 10):
            print 'You\'ve won a', skins[2]
        elif (randomchance() >= 5):
            print 'You\'ve won a', skins[3]
        elif (randomchance() >= 1):
            if randomknife == 1:
                print 'You\'ve won a', knifes[0]
            elif randomknife() == 2:
                print 'You\'ve won a', knifes[1]
            elif randomknife() == 3:
                print 'You\'ve won a', knifes[2]
            elif randomknife() == 4:
                print 'You\'ve won a', knifes[3]
            elif randomknife() == 5:
                print 'You\'ve won a', knifes[4]
            elif randomknife() == 6:
                print 'You\'ve won a', knifes[5]
            elif randomknife() == 7:
                print 'You\'ve won a', knifes[6]
            elif randomknife() == 8:
                print 'You\'ve won a', knifes[7]
        keys -= 1        

    elif(resp == str('no') or resp==str('No')):
        resp1=raw_input('Would you like to exit? Enter no for exit: ')
        if resp1 == 'no' or "No":
            exit()
    else:
        print "Yes or No. Answers only"
else:
    print 'You\'ve run out of keys!'
```

Comment: for debugging purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Konstantin has the right answer for how to choose the random number just once before testing all your conditions.

As to your second question (how to use less code to test all the conditions), take a look at my rewrite/cleanup below. In particular, I used `random.choice` to pick a knife, and I used a list of thresholds (35, 20, etc.) to pick skins.

I also fixed up a couple bugs, like your `if resp1 == 'no' or "No":` which should be `if resp1 == 'no' or resp1 == "No":` (but I used `resp1.lower()` instead).

And I couldn't stand `'Would you like to exit? Enter no for exit: '`, so I made "yes" exit instead. :-)

```
import random

skins = ['blue', 'purple', 'pink', 'red']
knives = ['karambit', 'flip', 'bowie', 'butterfly', 'm9 bayonet', 'bayonet', 'daggers', 'falchion']

print 'Welcome to CS GO case lottery'

print "Available skins: %s" % ', '.join(skins)
print "Available knives: %s" % ', '.join(knives)
print '(blue = common, purple = uncommon, pink = rare, red = epic)'

for _ in range(10):
    resp = raw_input("Enter 'yes' to open a case: ")
    while resp.lower() != 'yes':
        if resp.lower() == 'no':
            if raw_input('Would you like to exit? ').lower() == 'yes':
                exit()
        else:
            print "Yes or no answers only."
        resp = raw_input("Enter 'yes' to open a case: ")

    print 'Opening case...'

    chance = random.randint(1, 100)

    for i, n in enumerate([35, 20, 10, 5]):
        if chance >= n:
            print "You've won a %s skin." % skins[i]
            break

    if chance < 5:
        print "You've won a %s knife." % random.choice(knives)

print "You've run out of keys!"
```

Comment: "And I couldn't stand 'Would you like to exit? Enter no for exit: ', so I made "yes" exit instead. :-)" I put it there on purpose to see who will actually check all the code :-) looks like you got it

Comment: I just ran your code and it came with an error: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/caseopenv2", line 26, in <module>
    print "You've won a {} skin.".format(skins[i])
ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: What version of Python are you using? (`python --version` should tell you)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see you're using Python 2.6. That syntax won't work there... give me a second...

Comment: See my updated code, which should work with Python 2.6. But also, do yourself a favor and upgrade to Python 2.7 (or Python 3.5).

Comment: I am restricted to stick with python 2.6 because school laptop. Downloads wont work

Comment: How to print chance with "You've won a" on one line?

Comment: @AliS What? Are you asking how to reduce some portion of the code to one line? (If so, what code?) Or how to print something different from what is already printed? (If so, what do you want to print?)

Comment: What is the underscore for after the for?  Why did you add 'enumerate'?

Comment: A typical `for` loop looks like `for x in y: print x`. But if you're not using `x`, a convention I like is to write `for _ in y: ...` to signify that you're not actually using the value. Here I just wanted to run the loop 10 times, but I don't need to know which number I'm on.

Comment: `enumerate` is there because I want the value but also it's position. `for n in [35, 20, 10, 5]: ...` would just give me 35, 20, 10, and 5. But I want to know which `skin` to give out for each, so I also want the numbers 0, 1, 2, and 3. `enumerate` gives you the index and the value at the same time. So `for i, n in enumerate([35, 20, 10, 5]): ...` means I get `i = 0, n = 35` and then `i = 1, n = 20`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save to a variable before if/else statement:

```
number = randomchance();
if (number >= 35): print 'you select a ', number
```

Comment: its not 'you select a '. It's 'with a chance of '. But anyways I have to print the list's index so how to print number with it as well?

Answer (score -1):

This is how I would do it:

```
knives = ['karambit', 'flip', 'bowie', 'butterfly', 'm9 bayonet', 'bayonet', 'daggers', 'falchion']
skins = ['blue'] * 35 + ['purple'] * 20 + ['pink'] * 10 + ['red'] * 5 + [0]
skin = random.choice(skins)
print "You won a " + skin + " skin" if skin else "You won a " + random.choice(knives) + " knife"
```